# Toggle From Right to Left

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3, alloy-ui

Using AlloyUI `Toggler`, is it possible to toggle a div from right to left, rather than the standard down->up? I've checked the [`Toggler` API](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Toggler.html) but can't find any kind of toggle `direction`.

Here is my current `Toggler` code:

```
new Y.Toggler({
    animated : true,
    closeAllOnExpand : true,
    container : '#mySearchForm',
    content : '.content',
    expanded : false,
    header : '.header',
    transition : {
            duration : 0.2,
            easing : 'cubic-bezier(0, 0.1, 0, 1)'
    }//always toggles from the bottom->up
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `Toggler` to toggle horizontally, you need to do 3 things:

1. Apply `float: left;` to all `Toggler` elements to make the `Toggler` horizontal.
2. Change `animated: true,` to:

   ```
   animated: {
       to: { right : '300px' }
   },
   ```

   **Note:** You may need to adjust the exact number of pixels.
3. Change [`Toggler`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Toggler.html) to [`TogglerDelegate`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TogglerDelegate.html).

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50emrt7g/1/) with all of that put together with your original code.

Check out the YUI [`Anim`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Anim.html) and [`Easing`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Easing.html) classes for more details on how to modify animations.